# A tibble with a list as a column into long format in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

Let's assume we have a following tibble:

```
set.seed(123)

mightyTibble <- tibble(
   year = 1:10,
   revenue = 1000*rgamma(10,2000,3000),
   cost = 100*rgamma(10,2000,3000),
   items = lapply(1:10, \(i) runif(rpois(1,6), 10, 20))
)

mightyTibble
# A tibble: 10 × 4
    year revenue  cost items    
   <int>   <dbl> <dbl> <list>   
 1     1    658.  67.2 <dbl [2]>
 2     2    684.  66.8 <dbl [3]>
 3     3    642.  65.8 <dbl [8]>
 4     4    668.  68.6 <dbl [8]>
 5     5    692.  67.9 <dbl [4]>
 6     6    673.  66.6 <dbl [4]>
 7     7    648.  65.9 <dbl [5]>
 8     8    641.  66.3 <dbl [7]>
 9     9    685.  65.1 <dbl [6]>
10    10    672.  66.5 <dbl [9]>
```

Now, how can this be put into a long format neatly? So far I tried `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` package, but it cannot handle list columns if I have understood correctly.

Comment: `unnest()` the column before pivoting, or look at `unnest_longer()` for your dataset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`unnest_longer` is what you are looking for -

```
library(tidyr)
mightyTibble %>% unnest_longer(items)

# A tibble: 56 × 4
#    year revenue  cost items
#   <int>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1    658.  67.2  14.4
# 2     1    658.  67.2  18.0
# 3     2    684.  66.8  15.6
# 4     2    684.  66.8  12.1
# 5     2    684.  66.8  11.3
# 6     3    642.  65.8  19.0
# 7     3    642.  65.8  13.7
# 8     3    642.  65.8  16.7
# 9     3    642.  65.8  10.9
#10     3    642.  65.8  13.8
# ℹ 46 more rows
```